# replace \n with <br /> only on the all new lines before pre and after each pre tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using ajax with codeigniter to submit a preview of my question.

But I am trying to replace `\n` with `<br />` only on the all new lines before `pre` and after each `pre` tag.

Question: How can I make sure it replaces `\n` with `br only on the lines before and after each pre tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#preview-question').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('question/preview');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            title: $('#title').val(), 
            question: $('#question').val(),
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if (response.success) {
                $('#preview').html(response.question.replace(/\n/g, "<br />").before('pre').after('pre'));
                var htmlBRCleaned = $('#preview pre').html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/, '').replace('<br\/>', '').replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;"); 
                $('#preview pre').html(htmlBRCleaned);        
            } else {

            }
        }

    });

    e.preventDefault();  
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Question extends MY_Controller {

    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
    }

    public function create() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('question', 'question', 'trim|required|callback_question');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

        }

        $data['page'] = 'question/create';

        $this->load->view($this->config->item('config_template') . '/template/template_view', $data);
    }

    public function question() {
        if (empty($this->input->post('question'))) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('question', 'You have not asked a question');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function preview() {

        $data = array('success' => false, 'question' => '');

        if ($_POST) {

            $question = $this->input->post('question');

            $data['question'] =  $question;

            $data['success'] = true;
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: in php have you tried nl2br . 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Yes i have on controller did not work way was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a easy way to do that without parsing. Supose you don't wanna parsing, the easiest solution I think  is apply the CSS rule for entry question, like it was a PRE element.

```
#preview{
    white-space: pre;
}
```